# Bug on PowerPoint (Macros)

Tags: macros, powerpoint, slide

So I have 2 TextBoxes on a Slide, you write something on them and then you click on a object on the Slide and it executes a macro that makes you go to the next slide, in this slide you'll automatically be redirected to the next slide (Go to next Slide after 00:00,01). But the problem is that the Textboxes keep on the Slide, it's very wired. Like they don't disappear, because on the next slide there is no textbox. And then all the slides have theses textboxes... I don't know if you understood, but can someone help me please?

Comment: First, are you sure the text boxes are not on the slide master or one of the master layouts?

Comment: They only appear on other slides if I go to the slide where the textboxes are.

Comment: OK, then the textboxes are not likely on the master/layouts. To get more help with this, you'll want to post the code you're using (or a simplified version of it that produces the same result)